# Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 (Dell 1705): Bluetooth not detected

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, dell, atheros

I am a Windows user trying to adapt to Linux. Currently, I am running  Ubuntu 16.04.

Recently I changed my wireless card from a Realtek RT3290 with severe connection problems under Ubuntu and Mint for a Qualcomm QCA9565 also known as DELL 1705.

The problem is: I don't have bluetooth with neither card. Previously, with RT3290, the blutooth module coudn't load but I did see something bt related under "rfkill list". Now, I don't see anything at all!
This module was installed on a Dell Laptop with Windows and the bluetooth part worked just fine.

Here's some information:

```
angourakis@angourakis-nb ~ $ lsusb
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f3:0280 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:5775 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HP "Truevision HD" laptop camera
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

angourakis@angourakis-nb ~ $ uname -a
    Linux angourakis-nb 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

angourakis@angourakis-nb ~ $ ls -l /sys/class/bluetooth
    ls: cannot access '/sys/class/bluetooth': No such file or directory

angourakis@angourakis-nb ~ $ lsmod | grep bt
    btrfs                 987136  0
    xor                    24576  1 btrfs
    raid6_pq              102400  1 btrfs

angourakis@angourakis-nb ~ $ rfkill list
    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

angourakis@angourakis-nb ~ $ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
    08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:020c]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

angourakis@angourakis-nb ~ $ sudo modprobe ath9k && dmesg | grep ath
    [    3.836205] ath: phy0: WB335 1-ANT card detected
    [    3.836209] ath: phy0: Set BT/WLAN RX diversity capability
    [    3.845203] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
    [    3.846545] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
    [    3.846548] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
    [    3.846548] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
    [    3.846550] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
    [    3.846551] ath: Regpair used: 0x60
    [    4.014927] ath9k 0000:08:00.0 wlp8s0: renamed from wlan0
    [   10.366513] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x807c
    [   10.366516] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
    [   10.366517] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
    [   10.366518] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
    [   10.366520] ath: Country alpha2 being used: CA
    [   10.366520] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
    [   10.366522] ath: regdomain 0x807c dynamically updated by country IE
    [  730.476683] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x807c
    [  730.476686] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
    [  730.476686] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
    [  730.476687] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
    [  730.476688] ath: Country alpha2 being used: CA
    [  730.476689] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
    [  730.476690] ath: regdomain 0x807c dynamically updated by country IE
```

Do you have any suggestions? The strange thing is that I also tried installing Windows 10, but it didn't recognize my bluetooth either.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: It looks like the BT device is disabled in BIOS, or it may be blacklisted there, or it may be incompatible with the MB. It can't be resolved in the OS.

Comment: @Pilot6 oh right =( I don't have any option in the BIOS, so I think I should look for enabling such option. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 No WiFi adapter found \[Dell Inspiron 3542.\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061539/ubuntu-18-04-no-wifi-adapter-found-dell-inspiron-3542)