# Xubuntu Wireless Driver Trouble (Unclaimed network, iwlwifi, Intel AX200)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, xubuntu, iwlwifi

I recently ran `sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get upgrade` and after rebooting found that my wireless internet wasn't working anymore.

Here's what I'm running:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-45-generic
DE: Xfce
```

I ran `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:52:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ceb00000-ceb03fff
```

I ran `lspci` to find my network controller:

```
52:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
```

And `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`:

```
52:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0080]
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

And `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`:

```
[   11.790522] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[   11.790522] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8613:3ae69204
[   11.817749] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   12.217466] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:52:00.0 failed with error -110
```

From there on, however, I was lost. I followed instructions in a number of other posts and answers: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156167/unable-to-get-wifi-adapter-working-clean-19-04-install-network-unclaimed) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518571/locating-drivers-for-intel-ax200-wireless-on-5-1-kernel) [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149116/intel-wifi-support-for-ax200-cyclone-peak) [4](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless.html). Here's what I tried:

- I downloaded the [newest driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless.html) and copy-pasted it into `/lib/firmware`. Turns out I already had it.
- I tried installing the backport: `sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms`
- I tried installing a more complicated version of the backport:

```
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi/
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sudo make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

So I still haven't solved it, and I don't want to keep poking around solo (since I don't know what I'm doing and don't want to wreck my system). I'm posting here via USB/Ethernet, which works just fine. What's confusing me is that *I appear to have the right drivers installed* into `/lib/firmware`, but it still won't work. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it: I ran `apt-get --reinstall install linux-firmware`. The reinstall seems to have fixed whatever the underlying issue was. To quote [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1083468/266802):

> Don't try to manually install from an archive provided by Intel.
> Always try to find a package that provides the driver if possible.

I still get an ominous "system problem detected" GUI message on boot, but I'll let that sit for now.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the accepted solution.