# Sudden iwlwifi issues on 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

While my laptop (XPS 13) can technically connect to my WiFi, anything beyond a basic google search is impossible. Downloading and updating software is also impossible. I have tried this on multiple networks, and have confirmed that the issue is with my laptop’s network drivers.

lspci lists its network controller as `Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)`

I would start trying to fix this by reinstalling the drivers, but I don’t have an Ethernet adapter at the moment, so I wanted to know if there’s a way to fix this either *without* an internet, or by transferring files from a computer without a Linux OS.

lshw shows two Ethernet and no wireless network adapters for some reason

uname -a shows `5.4.0-45-generic #49~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP [timestamp that I’m too lazy to type] x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Update: I believe my card is an AX200. I downloaded the correct ucode file (iwlwifi-cc-46.3 etc) from Intel’s website and moved it to /lib/firmware. I’m not sure which firmware it is selecting, because modinfo iwlwifi gives 20 or so lines starting with “firmware:”, none of which is the one corresponding to the wireless adapter.

Comment: Can you please update you question with the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Edited to include uname

Comment: Also, according to user [anthony-souls](https://askubuntu.com/users/1123910/anthony-souls) you can use `modinfo iwlwifi | grep cc`

Comment: Additionally, it's kind of unclear if you are willing to use a different computer without a Linux OS to download the needed file. As the question is stated, it appears you are open to using a different computer to download the file but it also looks like that might not have been what you intended to say.

Comment: One more thing. If you absolutely cannot use another computer to download, you could run the following command to check for a cached version of the deb file that contains the needed file `ls /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware*`

Answer (score 1):

[According to other users](https://askubuntu.com/q/1272749/167115), you should use the Intel firmware that is available from Ubuntu instead of downloading it from the Intel website to avoid problems.

To fix your problem you will need to reinstall the `linux-firmware` package. As your question is stated, it appears you are open to using a different computer to download the needed file.

[You can download the needed file from here.](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.173.18_all.deb)

Then, transfer that file to your ~/Downloads directory on your Ubuntu computer.

Finally, make a backup of the existing firmware file (just in case) and reinstall the `linux-firmware` package by running the following commands:

```
mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode ~/Downloads/iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode-backup
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/linux-firmware*deb
```

Run the following command to verify the new file exists:

```
ls /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode
```

Save any unsaved work and reboot to apply the changes.

Comment: I installed and verified it by transferring the file from another computer, but I'm still having trouble. I also ended up getting an ethernet cord and adapter, and I tried ```sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-firmware``` and that didn't help either. I also tried editing ```/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf``` but that didn't help either. In adition, ```modinfo iwlwifi | grep cc``` does not list ```iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode```. Any idea where I can go from here?