# Ubuntu, kernel 5.8, wifi not working, no agent were available for this request

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

I'm wondering why my WiFi stops working suddenly. I can't figure out what is going wrong.

I'm using a laptop lenovo L13 Intel i7, running ubuntu 20.04 and Kde5.

All worked fine until some days ago when I realized that I couldn't connect to my usual WiFi. When I try to select one of my saved WiFi connection appears a pop-up with the following message:

```
Failed to get secrets for MIWIFI_aYEx
No agents were available for this request.
```

I posted the [wireless-info.txt](https://gist.github.com/mmngreco/6a87b94404515ef91427e7b86e3b4298), as the review process recommend.

Also, I've found and read the following related issues but I don't have the knowledge to continue alone:

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=226683
- https://forum.manjaro.org/t/iwlwifi-on-kernel-5-8-broken/23417

So, here are the common output requested for debugging.

My kernel:

```bsh
$ uname -r
5.8.0-48-generic
```

`iwlwifi` messages:

```bsh
$ journalctl -k -p 4 | grep iwlwifi
abr 09 21:09:43 mgreco kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
abr 09 21:09:43 mgreco kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
abr 09 21:09:43 mgreco kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
```

`iwlwifi` messages:

```bsh
$ dmesg | egrep "iwlwifi"
[    5.012141] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.022302] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.023653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    5.023663] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 65.3.35.22
[    5.023890] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.023912] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    5.066390] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x354
[    5.227639] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 14:f6:d8:84:25:92
[    5.245493] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
```

Here's the firware list:

```bsh
$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep firmware
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf-a0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf4-a0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-jf-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-56.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-56.ucode
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
```

I've read that `linux-firmware` maybe missing but is not the case:

```bsh
$ LANG=c dpkg -s linux-firmware
Package: linux-firmware
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 545755
Maintainer: Ubuntu Kernel Team <kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 1.187.10
Replaces: atmel-firmware, linux-firmware-snapdragon (<= 1.2-0ubuntu1), linux-restricted-common
Provides: atmel-firmware
Breaks: linux-firmware-raspi2 (<= 1.20190819-0ubuntu2), linux-firmware-snapdragon (<= 1.2-0ubuntu1)
Conflicts: atmel-firmware
Description: Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
 This package provides firmware used by Linux kernel drivers.
```

Here is my `iwlwifi.conf`

```bsh
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

Wireless info:

```bsh
$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for mgreco:
  *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9462
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 00
       serial: 14:f6:d8:84:25:92
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.u latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:71338000-7133bfff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 00
       serial: 48:2a:e3:86:99:f2
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:127 memory:71300000-7131ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:1
       logical name: enx3c18a054c684
       serial: 3c:18:a0:54:c6:84
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.11.11 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153a-3 v2 02/07/20 ip=192.168.31.205 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

Details of my PCI wireless card:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b0 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Wireless card is not blocked:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Firmware:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.291556] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.174304] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    1.588418] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x4f3001)
[    5.022302] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.022386] elan_i2c 0-0015: Elan Touchpad: Module ID: 0x0033, Firmware: 0x0001, Sample: 0x0000, IAP: 0x0000
[    5.023890] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.023912] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    5.166487] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 121 week 36 2020
```

Any help is welcome :-)

## Update 1

Answering the `guiverc` questions:

> A few days ago; do you update regularly?

Yes, I update packages frequently.

> did you try the prior kernel and did wifi work?

I've checked this [following this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/1097697/243254) which in summary consists in
restart the system, select the "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and choose the
kernel which was 5.4 in my case.

However this **doesn't fix the WiFi connection**.

> You can always opt to use the GA kernel (ie. remain on 5.4 the life of 20.04)
> but grub is usually used to try using older installed kernels first, to ensure
> it's a kernel update that caused the issue, or something else (eg. configuration
> issue etc), and you've not mentioned that diagnostic step.

Thank you, I saw how to do it in the question linked above.

## Update 2

I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1289040/243254) that fast boot can interfer my with wifi card. I've checked that
I have this option disabled.

Comment: A few days ago; do you update regularly? did you try the prior kernel and did wifi work?  You can always opt to use the GA kernel (ie. remain on 5.4 the life of 20.04) but `grub` is usually used to try using older installed kernels first, to ensure it's a kernel update that caused the issue, or something else (eg. configuration issue etc), and you've not mentioned that diagnostic step.

Comment: > A few days ago; do you update regularly?

Yes, I update packages frequently.

> did you try the prior kernel and did wifi work?

I've checked this [following this guide][1] which in summary consists in
restart the system, select the "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and choose the
kernel which was 5.4 in my case.

However this doesn't fix the WiFi connection problem.

[1]: https://askubuntu.com/a/1097697/243254