# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS slow WIFI speed Intel AX201

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, intel, iwlwifi

I'm using MSI Modern 15 A11SB as temporary replacement of my main laptop but I'm facing issues with speed of my internet.

Laptop is equipped with Intel AX201 WIFI 6 and the router (Linksys E900) is about 2-3 meters from me but my internet connection is poor.

I've read a lot and I've tried almost everything I found in internet about this issue but without success. I've tried:

- Disabling fast boot
- Changing kernel version (I've tried almost every minor version since 5.2)
- Disabling bluetooth
- Change value of `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Internet speed is up to 10Mbps while on my old laptop (ASUS Rog G552VW with Ubuntu 16.04) speed is up to 10-12 times faster placed on same spot.

Here is some debug information:

`uname -a` output

```
Linux gtsvetanov 5.11.0-40-generic #44~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 26 18:07:44 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lshw -c network` output

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 20
       serial: d8:f8:83:0b:e4:9c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-40-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.u ip=192.168.1.140 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:19 memory:603318c000-603318ffff
```

`inxi -Fxz` output

```
System:    Kernel: 5.11.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: Modern 15 A11SB v: REV:1.0 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-1552 v: REV:1.0 serial: <filter> UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: E1552IMS.10B 
           date: 11/03/2020 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 43.3 Wh condition: 45.4/52.4 Wh (87%) model: MSI Corp. MS-1552 status: Unknown 
           Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech Marathon Mouse/Performance Plus M705 charge: 55% (should be ignored) 
           status: Discharging 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Tiger Lake rev: 1 
           L2 cache: 12.0 MiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 44851 
           Speed: 1100 MHz min/max: 400/4700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1168 2: 1180 3: 1200 4: 1200 5: 1148 6: 1100 7: 1100 
           8: 1100 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 2f:00.0 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa tty: N/A 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: sof-audio-pci bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-40-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 4000 bus ID: 00:14.3 
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 293.99 GiB (61.6%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Micron model: 2210 MTFDHBA512QFD size: 476.94 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 467.96 GiB used: 293.96 GiB (62.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 43.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 378 Uptime: 26m Memory: 15.34 GiB used: 3.74 GiB (24.4%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 
           Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

`dmesg | grep iwlwifi` output

```
[    1.987118] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.999254] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    1.999267] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 65.3.35.22
[    1.999494] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.178304] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x354
[    2.361884] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: d8:f8:83:0b:e4:9c
[    2.376429] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   61.033395]  crct10dif_pclmul mc ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq aesni_intel snd_seq_device snd_timer crypto_simd i915 cryptd glue_helper nouveau snd iwlwifi intel_cstate drm_ttm_helper ttm joydev input_leds drm_kms_helper mei_me cfg80211 serio_raw mei wmi_bmof efi_pstore cec msi_wmi soundcore rc_core ee1004 mxm_wmi i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea hid_multitouch sysfillrect processor_thermal_device sysimgblt processor_thermal_rfim processor_thermal_mbox processor_thermal_rapl intel_rapl_common intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class intel_soc_dts_iosf mac_hid int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone intel_hid int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel soc_button_array sparse_keymap acpi_pad acpi_tad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul psmouse i2c_i801 i2c_smbus rtsx_pci intel_lpss_pci thunderbolt nvme intel_lpss idma64 nvme_core xhci_pci virt_dma intel_pmt xhci_pci_renesas i2c_hid hid video wmi pinctrl_tigerlake
```

`lsmod | grep iwlwifi` output

```
iwlwifi               372736  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              888832  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

Comment: Why don't you boot from a live usb, maybe with Ubuntu 18 or 16 and see how fast the wifi gets?

Comment: Please post the output of commands listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1374564/226614), under "Output of commands", using of course `iwlwifi` for the driver. You already posted some of this.
And I apologize in advance for the "self-promotion", but you might find useful info [here](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=user%3A226614+wifi). I helped in several, seemingly similar or related, problems. I am giving the pointer here since I am familiar with that.

Comment: Your higher chances are with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371229/killer-wi-fi-6-ax1650i-wifi-slow-connections-on-5-11-kernel/1372187#1372187) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1340193/226614) (same driver).

Comment: Also specify:
1) What you did for "Disabling bluetooth".
2) What did you "Change value of /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf" to.

Comment: Try with different router, with all the failed workarounds reverted back

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that Intel AX201 is not compatible with Ubuntu 20.04.
([source](http://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Intel-Wi-Fi-6-AX201-Linux-Ubuntu-20-04-Slow-speeds-and/m-p/1290482#M36297)).
From this point on, you might try workarounds.
For instance, it looks like 18.04 with kernel > 5.2 might work.
For this sake, some information is required, see comments [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374809/ubuntu-20-04-lts-slow-wifi-speed-intel-ax201#comment2368345_1374809) and following.

**Related** (you surely already found some of this):

1. [Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX201 module causing Wi-Fi not detected errors upon fresh install, Ubuntu 18.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196370/intel-wi-fi-6-ax201-module-causing-wi-fi-not-detected-errors-upon-fresh-install) (Is [this](https://ubuntu.forumming.com/question/360/intel-174-wi-fi-6-ax201-module-causing-wi-fi-not-detected-errors-upon-fresh-install-ubuntu-18-04lts) replicating the contents, but with fake names??)
2. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=321521
3. [WiFi Adapter AX201 Just Doesn't Work Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285506/wifi-adapter-ax201-just-doesnt-work-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: No success with any of these. I've tried too many times too many fixes without success.

Comment: @GTsvetanov - Did you try with Ubuntu 18.04?
As the **official channel** shows, a solution may simply not exist at this point, with 20.04.

Comment: yes, it works like in 20.04 - slow wifi speed but it "works".