# Intel 9260 has no wifi on battery power with 20.04 LTS and any kernel 5.8 up to 5.10 (HP Laptop w Ryzen 3 3250u)

Tags: iwlwifi

I recently bought a new laptop (HP with a Ryzen 3 3250u) which I dual boot with windows 10.
I installed (upgraded to) a Intel ac-9260 .
When the laptop is on battery power and on a kernel 5.8 and newer, it has no connection. It doesn't see the card at all in iwconfig .

When I plug in the power, it connects right away and works great. Shows up where its supposed to.

i have no issues on 5.4.0.54 .  ( I did have a similar issue in Windows 10 that was corrected by a setting tweak telling it not to power save)

I tried editing /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and setting

wifi.powersave = 2
This did nothing.

Sudo modinfo iwlwifi still shows

parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)

parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)

Everything works fine on the earlier kernel.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's your Wi-Fi card chipset? Try `lspci | grep "Wireless"` in a terminal.

Comment: Here;s what it says:       02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)

Comment: Try the answer posted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083369/ubuntu-18-04-cannot-recognized-intel-wireless-ac-9260

Comment: Went through everything in that post , no change.  The strange part is, it works fine as soon as the ac power adapter is plugged in. If I start the computer on battery and leave it on battery, the network card does not work. Does anyone know how to disable the power management mode of that intel 9260 in l the newer kernels?

Comment: Try editing `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` as suggested here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2387479&s=5bf7a56e9ccd6a112455c3f3ca917589&p=13753362#post13753362