# Why can't I find my Wi-fi Adapter on Ubuntu 18.04 considering it was working perfectly a few days ago?

Tags: 18.04, drivers, wireless, dell, adapter

I am aware of all of the similar questions on this forum regarding this issue. I have followed each post that gives general advice on how to fix my "no wi-fi adapter found" error from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416180/ubuntu-no-wifi-adapter-found to [Ubuntu 18.04 No WiFi adapter found [Dell Inspiron 3542.]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061539/ubuntu-18-04-no-wifi-adapter-found-dell-inspiron-3542).

I receive my Dell Precision 5540 a few weeks ago. The Wi-fi adapter was working just fine. Out of no where, the Wi-fi adapter was not available. This happened a little after I updated my BIOS, which was a recommended update, and I transferred ownership of my laptop from the retailer.

Ubuntu 18.04 was installed for me. Here is my output:

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

```
mikel@mikel-Precision-5540:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4080]
3c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [1028:0906]
```

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
mikel@mikel-Precision-5540:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4080]
3c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
```

sudo rfkill list

```
mikel@mikel-Precision-5540:~$ sudo rfkill list
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
mikel@mikel-Precision-5540:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ed400000-ed403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enx3448edc97b27
       serial: 34:48:ed:c9:7b:27
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.09.9 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.155 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

dmesg | grep ath9k

```
no output
```

sudo iw dev

```
no output
```

mokutil --sb-state; modinfo iwlwifi

```
mikel@mikel-Precision-5540:~$ mokutil --sb-state; modinfo iwlwifi
SecureBoot disabled
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-1079-oem/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0-38.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-b0-38.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-a0-38.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-hr-a0--38.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-jf-b0--38.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-f0-hr-a0--38.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0--38.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0--38.ucode
srcversion:     4E5682727AA9D4F14E07C43
alias:          pci:v00008086d000040C0sv*sd00000A10bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000040C0sv*sd00000000bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002720sv*sd00000310bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002720sv*sd00000090bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002720sv*sd00001080bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002720sv*sd00000030bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002720sv*sd00000070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002720sv*sd00000078bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000034F0sv*sd00000070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002720sv*sd00000000bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000034F0sv*sd00000310bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002720sv*sd00000A10bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd000042A4bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00004234bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd000040A4bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00004034bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00004030bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00002034bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00002030bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00001552bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00001551bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00001210bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00001030bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00001010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd000002A4bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd000002A0bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00000264bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00000260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd0000023Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00000238bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00000234bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00000230bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd000000A4bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       4.15.0-1079-oem SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
```

Should I just do a factory reset? I have no clue why I have not been able to get my Wi-fi adapter working considering it was working fine a few days ago.

**update:**

sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms

```
mikel@mikel-Precision-5540:~$ sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
[sudo] password for mikel: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
backport-iwlwifi-dkms is already the newest version (8042-0ubuntu1pop1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Please edit to include result for `mokutil --sb-state; modinfo iwlwifi`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I added the result for mokutil command. Please let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to install the backport-iwlwifi-dkms from the driver manager and reboot

Comment: Check your BIOS-EFI settings and try to disable everything related to "secure EFI feature".  It might have been turned on after bios update and your wireless internal card might not be digitally signed doe linux.

Comment: @Jeremy31 I added the output of sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms. Apparently, I already had the newest version. Is there a way to install it from the driver manager if I already have it installed on my machine? Any other suggestions?

Comment: @kcdtv I am very reluctant to change things in BIOS. Do you mind explaining what disabling "secure EFI features" will do to my machine. Although it may resolve this issue, will my computer be more vulnerable following this change?

Comment: No. All this efi secure features are bullshit, it is to secure a mallware called windows. And it can be easly bypassed. And if you think about meltdwon and spectre or the mimix secretly (not anymore) embed in Intel chipsets ... My old desktop with it all school BIOS and it ubuntu will always be more secure then any windows machine with it efi and whatever.