# No WIFI QUALCOMM QCA6174

Tags: networking, drivers

I should start with the near ubiquitous line "total newb of newbs here", so please be patient, thanks.

So I've been running U22.04 for quite a while now and had no problems at all until I installed the latest VirtualBox and USB extension.  I think this is where the problem started, but it's just a guess really.

Everything seemed to go fine. I had WiFi connectivity after the installation with no worries.

I then started to experience a problem with the archive manager hanging, then files. I didn't really understand what was happening so I restarted the machine.

That's when the problem started. Reboot was fine except for the complete absence of WIFI.

I have been trolling through the internet for a solution, but have had no luck yet.

As far as I can tell from what I think I've tested, the adapter is working fine, there's just no drivers for it.  I have tried a solution that looked like almost the same problem as I have, but it didn't work.

At this point I am sitting with a fresh reinstall of 22.04.

Adapter list:

[image: Adapter list]

Install list:

[image: Install list]

Wi-Fi settings:

[image: Wi-Fi settings]

The question is not answered because the link provided only demonstrates the information that people would like to see in an attempt to answer the question, not actually answer it.

And this link is the answer to the question that I have been asked;

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/9VkbZy5WT3/

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 20 Dec 2023 18:09 CST -0600

Booted last: 20 Dec 2023 00:00 CST -0600

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

##### kernel ############################

Linux 6.2.0-39-generic #40~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov 16 10:53:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

3b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e0a1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Device [0707:2400]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

3c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Rivet Networks Killer Wireless-n/a/ac 1535 Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1bcf:2b8c Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e300 Qualcomm Atheros Communications QCA61x4 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 187c:0528 Alienware Corporation AW1517
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

ath10k_pci             61440  0
ath10k_core           737280  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    36864  1 ath10k_core
dell_wmi               28672  0
mac80211             1617920  1 ath10k_core
dell_smbios            28672  1 dell_wmi
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 dell_wmi
dell_wmi_descriptor    20480  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
wmi_bmof               16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
cfg80211             1241088  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
video                  73728  3 dell_wmi,i915,nvidia_modeset
wmi                    40960  7 video,intel_wmi_thunderbolt,dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor,mxm_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp59s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp59s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.0.102/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp59s0
       valid_lft 6685sec preferred_lft 6685sec
    inet6 fe80::eba8:36d0:1d5f:62dc/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp60s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp60s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp59s0   no wireless extensions.

wlp60s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=-2147483648 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp59s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp59s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp59s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.102 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         582       1  0 18:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp59s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         alx
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.2.0-39-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp59s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:3b:00.0/net/enp59s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:3b:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp59s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       ec2c23e6-4e62-37bc-afb0-d2bfea5e7f7b
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.102/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 7200
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        expiry = 1703124027
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.0.102
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::eba8:36d0:1d5f:62dc/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   ec2c23e6-4e62-37bc-afb0-d2bfea5e7f7b | Wired connection 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp60s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath10k_pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.2.0-39-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp60s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:3c:00.0/net/wlp60s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:3c:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               yes
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp59s0   no frequency information.

wlp60s0   32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp59s0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp60s0   Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

##### module infos ######################

[ath10k_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac WLAN PCIe/AHB devices
depends:        ath10k_core
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath10k_pci
vermagic:       6.2.0-39-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint)
parm:           reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)

[ath10k_core]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Core module for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac wireless LAN cards.
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath10k_core
vermagic:       6.2.0-39-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug_mask:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           uart_print:Uart target debugging (bool)
parm:           skip_otp:Skip otp failure for calibration in testmode (bool)
parm:           cryptmode:Crypto mode: 0-hardware, 1-software (uint)
parm:           frame_mode:Datapath frame mode (0: raw, 1: native wifi (default), 2: ethernet) (uint)
parm:           coredump_mask:Bitfield of what to include in firmware crash file (ulong)
parm:           fw_diag_log:Diag based fw log debugging (bool)

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath
vermagic:       6.2.0-39-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       6.2.0-39-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       6.2.0-39-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath10k_pci]
irq_mode: 0
reset_mode: 0

[ath10k_core]
coredump_mask: 3
cryptmode: 0
debug_mask: 0
frame_mode: 1
fw_diag_log: N
skip_otp: N
uart_print: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    5.102594] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 706c395e
[    5.184846] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: htt-ver 3.60 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    5.270118] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[    5.270122] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    5.270125] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    5.270126] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[    5.277898] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0 wlp60s0: renamed from wlan0
[    6.012622] alx 0000:3b:00.0 enp59s0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full
[    6.012843] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp59s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: In your adapter list, you have an interface wlp60s0, firmware and everything you need. We don't understand what is not working. Please run the script @waltinator suggests and post the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Details at link following;  https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/9VkbZy5WT3/

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot.  Thanks for the welcome, glad to be here.  I've got heaps of questions.  This is just the start so I can get to the other questions.  :)

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Comment: "dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes" Have you tried the wireless switch or key combination on your Dell?

Comment: Probable solution; please test: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061539/ubuntu-18-04-no-wifi-adapter-found-dell-inspiron-3542